# QObject setProperty in a for loop reading an asio socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, boost-asio, qtquick2

I have a Qt C++ app, and I want to update a `Text QML Type` text property in the QML part while reading from a socket using `asio`.
The following code is invoked by a `QML Signal` which is connected to a `C++ Signal slot`.

```
try { // try to connect to the server
    asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

    // listen to server
    for (;;){
        std::vector<char> buf(128);
        asio::error_code error;
        size_t len = socket.read_some(asio::buffer(buf) , error);

        if (error == asio::error::eof) {
            break;
        } // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
        else if (error) {
            throw asio::system_error(error);
        } // Some other error.

        qDebug() << buf.data();
        qDebug() << "msg len: " << len;
        if (serverTextOutput){
            serverTextOutput->setProperty("text", buf.data() );
        }
    }
```

where `serverTextOutput` is my `Text QML Type` object.

This code works fine when I remove the `for loop` so I suspect the issue is that as the function never returns the QML UI is not updated (the new `text` property is not displayed). How should I handle this ?

Comment: What is the issue that you see when you have the for loop ? Is `eof` the correct and the only condition for it to break the loop ?

Comment: "What is the issue that you see when you have the for loop" +1 Since this looks like a UI application, where's the UI event loop? How does the UI update since you're in a tight loop, and never seem to yield control to the GUI framework? Does debug logging work?

Comment: Yes debug log works, `qDebug() << buf.data()` works. Just the UI is not updated.
I am having a try with asio::async_read() it might fix this issue

Comment: @jmatthieu  I hate to do the guess work, but is it that your for loop never ends and thats why UI is not updated ? OR it does come out of for loop and still your UI does not get updated or whatever that means.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but yes I reckon the issue is due to the fact I never exit the for loop.

Comment: If you go to the length of using **a**sio, you might do the last step of actually leveraging the asynchrony it provides :)

Comment: Yes I figured that currently trying to use async_read() instead

Comment: You should also seriously reconsider how you interact with QML.
Calling methods on QML instantiated objects is usually the least ideal option. The description sounds like the use case of a QString property and a slot on the C++ interface object

Comment: @KevinKrammer I currently use `QObject *serverTextOutput = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("server_output_window");` and then `serverTextOutput->setProperty()` I am not sure I understood what you said: should I use a C++ signal connected to a QML slot to update my Text text property ?

Comment: Can't you just emit a signal on the C++ side and the QML side can subscribe to that via Connections QML type ?

Comment: @jmatthieu right, this approach is often taken by people new to C++/QML integration. The draw backs are that you rely on specific objects of specific types being present with specific object names, which limits you considerably what you can do on the QML side.

The better approach is to let the QML side call into C++ and use values exported from C++. I.e. the ore dynamic QML side depends on things existing in the more static C++ side, not the other way around. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html#setting-an-object-as-a-context-property for the basic technique

Comment: @jmatthieu also see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html for using a property to for providing data, like your text, dynamically to QML, i.e. such that the C++ code can notify about a change in data and the QML side will update itself with it's usual binding mechanism

Comment: @KevinKrammer thanks that really helped me!